# Eigen: automatic/symbolic differentiation

Tags: c++, eigen, autodiff

I'm looking for a cpp auto/symb diff library that can work with Eigen elements.
One important feature that I need is that the derivative function (or expression tree) is calculated once and then can be evaluated in multiple points (I use it for optimization).

Options that I've considered so far:

1. Eigen's autodiff module.
   It's unsupported, and I'm not sure about it's capabilities.
2. autodiff.github.io.
   Doesn't have the feature that I need: the derivative needs to be recomputed for every point.
3. Casadi.
   Doesn't support Eigen. Moreover, its doc on cpp is meager and outdated (at least for vector algebra), and it feels like it's not encouraged to work with it directly from cpp.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the wrong impression and the feature I'm looking for won't do me much good. Therefore, the second option is probably the best. Relevant discussions:

https://github.com/autodiff/autodiff/issues/119

https://groups.google.com/g/casadi-users/c/g_M2-2nxoHA/m/qaE1861MBgAJ